# Is LinkedTransferQueue blocking or not-blocking queue?

Tags: java, multithreading, data-structures, queue

I read about concurrent queue in java, and i received confusion about LinkedTransferQueue. What is type of LinkedTransferQueue (is it blocking or not-blocking queue)? I have read that LinkedTransferQueue uses a CAS (compare and swap) approach and park method from Unsafe, and consists from nodes and pointers like ConcurrentLinkedQueue, it pushed on idea that it's a **non-blocking** queue. But interface TransferQueue extends **BlockingQueue**. It looks ambiguous. In the end, is LinkedTransferQueue blocking or not-blocking queue?

Comment: Are you wondering if `TransferQueue` is blocking or if `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` is blocking?  The former is blocking, the latter is not

Comment: I am wondering that factual ConcurrentLinkedQueue is blocking, but it is implemented by using non-blocking algorithm, because of this TransferQueue mustn't extends BlockingQueue

Comment: Why are you asking about `TransferQueue` (which is an interface), and `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` (which is a class that does _not_ implement `TransferQueue`) in the same question?  And, what are you asking that is not obvious when you read the javadoc?

Comment: I'm sorry, i made the mistake in the wording of question (i mistakenly type ConcurrentLinkedQueue instead of LinkedTransferQueue), i changed it to correct.

Comment: After the title and content change it is unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @EJP  I asked a question and received answer which solved it. What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `LinkedTransferQueue` is an unbounded queue so though it is `BlockingQueue` it will never actually reach the common producer/consumer patterns normal BlockingQueue implementations may achieve.

So, is it or isn't it blocking? It actually depends on the operation. For example, a few are listed below.

Non-blocking operations:

- `offer`
- `put`
- `add`
- `poll`
- `tryTransfer`

Blocking operations:

- `take`
- `transfer`

Point is, if an operation can achieve without blocking it will. Since the LinkedTransferQueue is forced to be unbounded, it can get away with both blocking and non-blocking operations.

If interested, I found this out by going through the Java 8 implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations about methods, it clarified the situation. How do you distinguish diff between blocking and non-blocking methods? Secondly, what do you meant about Producer/Consumer and LinkedTransferQueue?

Comment: A typical producer/consumer usage is something like *If there is room in this queue put this element on the queue, if not wait until there is room and vice versa*. The `LinkedTransferQueue` has two blocking modes since there is no fixed size. **1.** Wait for an element to exist in this queue. **2.** Wait for a consuming thread to be on this queue

Comment: In terms of distinguishing. I looked at the code for putting and there is a flag that says what type of operation we should do. `SYNC`, `ASYNC`, `NOW`, `TIMED`. sync and timed are your blocking operations while async and now are non-blocking.

Comment: Lastly, your intuition is right, "How can this be a blocking queue when it shares many features of the ConcurrentLinkedQueue" I had also wondered it as well.

Comment: It's very clear explanation, thank you for this. But why you said: "it will never actually reach the common producer/consumer patterns normal" ?

Comment: If you read about the producer/consumer pattern, (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem) it may be clear why a bounded queue is necessary. The `ArrayBlockingQueue` and `LinkedBlockingQueue` are both able to be bounded which means you can force threads to wait until there is room on the queue to put or elements on the queue to take. You lose this feature with an unbounded queue (like `LinkedTransferQueue` or `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`)

Comment: That is what a normal producer/consumer implementation consists of.

Comment: It means that `LinkedBlockingQueue` or `ArrayBlockingQueue` have better performance on Producer/Consumer task than `LinkedTransferQueue`?

Comment: No, it means that the `LinkedTransferQueue` cannot achieve the producer/consumer pattern. One requirement *is a bounded queue* which the LTQ is not.

Comment: However, that may not be a problem, it depends on your use case. If you do not need a fixed-size queue, then use a `LinkedTransferQueue` over the others. The `LinkedTransferQueue` will perform better than `ArrayBlockingQueue` or `LinkedBlockingQueue`

Comment: Every **bounded** queue in any programming language is not appropriate for producer/consumer problem. Is my insight true?

Comment: The inverse. Every **bounded blocking queue** should be appropriate for the producer/consumer pattern.

Comment: I made mistake. I would like to say unbounded. In the end, "Every **unbounded** queue in any programming language is not appropriate for producer/consumer problem", is it a true statement?

Comment: It is a blocking queue. It implements `BlockingQueue`, and `take()` [waits if necessary until an element becomes available](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html#take--).

Answer (score 0):

From the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html):

> An optionally-bounded blocking queue based on linked nodes.